# Selecting last orders for each user using Npgsql and EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have an `Order` entity with 2 main columns named `UserId` and `CreationTimeUtc`. What I'm trying to do is to select last `Order` for each user (based on `UserId` column of course). Normally I expect to do so by grouping and ordering. Here is what I've tried:

```
var q = _context.Orders.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(t => t.CreationTimeUtc > SomeDate)
    .GroupBy(t => t.UserId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(t => t.CreationTimeUtc).First())
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

But running the query couses this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (r.UserId), 
>   ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
>       EntityType: Order
>       ValueBufferExpression: 
>           (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>       IsNullable: False )

I googled a lot and it seems EF Core doesn't support grouping! Is this true? And if so, how can I solve the problem? Do I need to load all rows in memory or is there any LINQ-based way? Have you any idea? Thanks in advance.

I'm using `EF Core 3.1`, `ASP.NET Core 3.1`, `Npgsql 3.1`, `PostgreSQL 12`, and `C# 8`.

Comment: Would you consider a raw sql method?

Comment: @CaiusJard I prefer not to use row SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the following:

```cs
var result = ctx.Users
    .Select(u => u.Orders
        .Where(t => t.CreationTimeUtc > someDate)
        .OrderBy(t => t.CreationTimeUtc)
        .First())
    .ToList();
```

It's a slightly different way to express pretty much the same thing. I'll follow up with the relevant person to see about translating your specific pattern.

Comment: "your specific pattern" is soo common pattern supported by EF6 query translator (without client evaluation!). Remember part of the [Query with GroupBy or GroupJoin throws exception #17068](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068) discussion? It ended up with [Translate GroupBy followed by FirstOrDefault over group #12088](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12088) and the more general [Support ability to select top N of each group #13805](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13805) - both as "enhancement" in **Backlog**, i.e. - well, you know, some day may be...

Comment: Am  not saying it shouldn't be translated - but we definitely prioritize patterns where there's no workaround; in this case you can at least produce the right SQL and result via another LINQ construct. Translating all possible LINQ constructs is an infinite task, and we're constantly working it.

Comment: I haven't access to Users' in this context. There is only `UserId` field in `Orders`.

Comment: But you could load the user, right? Does Order have a User navigation property? And where in your question does it state that your Order has a User or that it is needed? I see that you want most recent order per userid in the question - did you ask for something you didn't want?

Comment: @CaiusJard the order hasn't a User navigation property. Actually the user is on an external service and I haven't access to it. There is just User ID.

Comment: What SQL would you expect EF to generate in this case, if there's only the UserId field and no User?